# Office 365 Shared Excel Workbook Overwriting Last Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a office 365 shared excel document, where new jobs are added to a worksheet via a macro on a separate sheet (as it works out some departmental dates based on criteria entered). When a add job button is clicked, it should be finding the next empty row in the job history sheet and transposing the relevant data into the new row.

It works for the most part, but it seems sometimes when multiple copies are open and some users have the job history sheet filtered it overwrites a line of existing data instead if inputting onto a blank row.

Any ideas how to find out why? Or a solution?

Thanks in advance

```
Set WSAddJob = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Add Job")
Set WSJobHist = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Job History")
Set rng = Range("D3:D10,D13,D21:D25,E12,E21:E23,E23:E25")


If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If WSAddJob.Range("PSLNo").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter PSL No."
    Range("PSLNo").Activate
    Exit Sub
ElseIf WSAddJob.Range("WorksNo").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter Works Number"
    Range("WorksNo").Activate
    Exit Sub
ElseIf WSAddJob.Range("ClientName").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter Client Name"
    Range("ClientName").Activate
    Exit Sub
ElseIf WSAddJob.Range("Site").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter Site Name"
    Range("Site").Activate
    Exit Sub
ElseIf WSAddJob.Range("DueDate").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter a Due Date"
    Range("DueDate").Activate
    Exit Sub
End If

' PSL number has been entered... now check for duplicates before commiting button
FindWhat = WSAddJob.Range("WorksNo").Value
Set FoundCell = WSJobHist.Range("SavedWorksNo").Find(What:=FindWhat, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Works Number " & FindWhat & " already in job history. Aborting..."
    Exit Sub
End If

mm = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = WSJobHist.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each c In rng
    WSJobHist.Cells(lastrow + 1, i) = c
    i = i + 1
```

Next

Comment: `lastrow = WSJobHist.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` should be changed to `lastrow = WSJobHist.Cells(WSJobHist.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` - **but** also you mention filters, and I think this method of finding last row might skip past hidden rows.

Comment: Thanks CLR. I don't care if it skips hidden rows when filtered. Just that it picks the next row after the last one full of data. It seems when the sheet is filtered, it sometimes picked up a row with data and overwrote. I'll try your tweak and see how it goes.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What I meant by 'skipping hidden rows' is in reference to the use of `End(xlUp).Row` - it scans from the bottom, up - but might not stop on the last populated row if that rows is hidden.

Comment: To find the last row of data, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba. If your data doesn't contain blank rows, `CurrentRegion` might be the easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

`.End(xlUp).Row` finds the last visble row. You could check the line is empty and increment if not.

```vb
lastrow = 1 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Do While Len(.Cells(lastrow, "A")) > 0
    lastrow = lastrow + 1
Loop
```

```vb
Sub demo()

    Dim wsAddJob As Worksheet, wsJobHist As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, dict As Object, k
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim WorksNo As String, FoundCell As Range
    
    ' define required fields
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dict
        .Add "PSLNo", "PSL No."
        .Add "WorksNo", "Works Number"
        .Add "ClientName", "Client Name"
        .Add "Site", "Site Name"
        .Add "DueDate", "a Due Date"
    End With
    
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsAddJob = .Sheets("Add Job")
        Set wsJobHist = Sheets("Job History")
    End With
    
    ' check entries
    With wsAddJob
        For Each k In dict.keys
           If Len(.Range(k).Value) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Enter " & dict(k), vbExclamation
                .Range(k).Activate
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        WorksNo = .Range("WorksNo")
        Set rng = .Range("D3:D10,D13,D21:D25,E12,E21:E23,E23:E25")
    End With
     
    'check if existing
    Set FoundCell = wsJobHist.Range("SavedWorksNo").Find(What:=WorksNo, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Works Number " & WorksNo & " already in job history row " & FoundCell.Row & _
                " Aborting...", vbCritical, FoundCell.Address
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim c
    With wsJobHist
        lastrow = 1 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Do While Len(.Cells(lastrow, "A")) > 0
            lastrow = lastrow + 1
        Loop
   
        For Each c In rng.Cells
           i = i + 1
           .Cells(lastrow, i) = c
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox "Record added row " & lastrow, vbInformation
End Sub
```